# Validação de Permissão - PHP

Tags: php

Estou com um problema em implementar a validação de uma página, pois ele sempre esta permitindo o usuário acessar a página independente do tipo de acesso, poderiam me ajudar?

Tipos de Acesso

1. Admin
2. Gerente
3. T.I
4. Colaborador

banco de dados

```
Tabela Usuário:
Id: 1
Nome: Bruno
Senha: 123
Permissão: 1
```

```php
session_start();

//Verifica se o usuário esta logado
$nome = $_SESSION['nome'];

if(!isset($nome)){
    header("location: ../index.php");
}



include_once ('../public/setting/conexaoBanco.php');
$mensagem = "";

$verificaPermissao = $conectarBanco->prepare("SELECT acesso FROM user where nome = '$nome'");
$verificaPermissao->execute();
$resultado = $verificaPermissao->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// dados do resultado = array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["acesso"]=> string(1) "4" } }

if($resultado > 1){
 header("location: restrito.php");
}else{
 $msg = "Seja bem vindo $_SESSION['nome']";
}
```

Comment: Você não devia verificar se `$resultado['acesso']` é maior que 1? Não faz sentido comparar um *array* com um inteiro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss então fiz de forma que você explicou porem ao validar a informação do array $resultado['acesso'] o mesmo retorna null sendo que se eu der um var_dump de $resultado apenas o mesmo retorna // dados do resultado = array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["acesso"]=> string(1) "4" } }

Comment: Ah, você utilizou o `fetchAll`, ele retorna um *array*, então ficaria `$resultado[0]['acesso']`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss deu certo!